# how to get List of Orders from Woocommerce API?

Tags: c#, api, rest, woocommerce

I am trying to get list of orders from Woocommerce using Latest REST API v3. I am using Basic Authentication. It is said that Woocommerce Supports basic Authentication for Https (SSL enable).

My code is below .

```
        WebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://shyamssaging.com:443/woocommerce/wc-api/v3/orders");
        string usernamePassword = "ck_255fd4ab5dfb235065932b5ed72f419a8c2659e2:cs_7f619115423ff9d9b845fca8ee7053ff01c4ab27";            
        myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(usernamePassword)));            
        WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
        Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Error is Unauthorized. Even,  i am using valid Userkey and secret key  .
Thanks 
Shyams

Answer (score 1):

There's a REST API Client Library you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/jakobt/b7400463e90e16928f57) , you'll need to make minor changes to the code.

1. Create a new class in your application called WoocommerceApiClient.cs and paste the code from the link above in it ( as I already mentioned you need to make minor changes )
2. You can then reference it using

   ```
   string ConsumerKey = "key";
   string ConsumerSecret = "secret";
   string StoreUrl = "https://www.fishbowlstaging.com";
   bool Isssl = true;

   WoocommerceApiClient client = new WoocommerceApiClient(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, StoreUrl, Isssl);
   string orders = client.GetProducts();
   ```

You can add more methods to the class as you require.

Comment: it is  not work for POST, it is Get Method which i have already done

Comment: I need basic authentication because i am using https

Comment: I have successfully tested the code and can tell you that you have a product called "B200" :) Besides you mentioned that you need pull a list of records which is going to be a Get request

Comment: yes, I am also getting list of product from Woocommerce api , but not able to create new product in Woocommerce using API. API documentation said you can use basic authentication for v3.  I need just post operation.

Comment: I found solution just by changing url